# AS3 Textfield href ampersand issue

Tags: actionscript-3, href, textfield, ampersand

I have a textfield with an  tag in htmlText. Everything works fine until the href contains an ampersand in the url (example: "example.aspx?param1=x&param2=y"), then flash stop filling the textField.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
example.aspx&amp;param1=x&amp;param2=y
```

?

Comment: var str:String = "<a href=\"example.aspx?param1=x&param2=y\">link</a><br />";
var txtField:TextField = new TextField();
txtField.htmlText = str;

Comment: There is obviously something wrong in your code, see my other answer

Comment: Excuse me, but i didn't see anything wrong in the code i've posted in my last answer. To change the ampersands by it's html entity didn't work for me. So if you are seeing something wrong please, tell me.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing in your code I think , here is a workable example

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class TestTextField extends Sprite
    {
        private var label:TextField;
        private var labelText:String = "<a href=\"example.aspx?param1=x&param2=y\">link</a><br />";


        public function TestTextField()
        {
            configureLabel();
            setLabel(labelText);
        }

        public function setLabel(str:String):void 
        {
            label.htmlText = str;
        }

        private function configureLabel():void {

            label = new TextField();
            addChild(label);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi again, it's something strange. Obviously my code is much large, but the fact is that if I change the url in the href attribute for another without ampersands it works. As soon as I put an ampersand in the url, it fails

Comment: Yup, that was basically what I tried to explain in my other comment. I think there is something else in your code that causes the problem. But I can't really tell you what it is since I haven't seen it

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but in my case, if you replaced the ampersand with `%26` (The url encoded version), it showed up just fine.